# Dividing one column with another in python is giving wrong result in pandas python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a data frame with integer values in each columns (A,B,C) and I am interested to derive another 2 columns (D, ac): D is the sum of the columns A,B,C and ac is derived by dividing values in A with values in D. But I am getting wrong output in D and ac columns:

[image]

My desired output will be as follows:

[image]

Comment: 1) The table you show is incorrect for code you've written. 2) Your code works fine, I literally copied it, and columns __D__ and __ac__ were calculated fine

Comment: Your random function returns floats not ints.

Comment: I have given screenshot of the code and output together. I am getting the output only. I have tried with another data: t = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3], 'b': [2,3,4], 'c':['dd','ee','ff'], 'd':[5,9,1]})
t['e'] = t.sum(axis=1)
t['ac'] = (t['a']/t['e'])
The sum is working fine but the column ac is still giving wrong output. I have no idea why.

Answer (score 0):

Your code woks fine I tried it .

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(10)
t=pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,3),columns=list('ABC'))
t['d']=t.sum(axis=1)
t['ac']=t['A']/t['d']
```

Answer (score 0):

I understood the problem. Initially I set pd.set_option('display.float_format', lambda x: '%.0f' % x) to remove scientific notation. That's why I was getting the error. With pd.set_option('display.float_format', lambda x: '%.5f' % x), the code is working fine.